# How to convert column data from text file into list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains data in two columns, each of which I want to read into Python as a list.

For example :

```
       2500.3410      -0.60960758
       2505.5803       -1.3031826
       2510.8197      -0.64067196
       2516.0593       -1.0230898
       2521.2991      -0.20078891
```

I want to create two lists, one containing the data from column 1 and the other column 2, but I don't know how to tell Python to do this.

E.g.

```
list1 = [2500.3410, 2505.5803, 2510.8197, 2516.0593, 2521.2991]
```

I have opened the file in the shell and can read in the data, as above, but I'm stuck when it comes to creating the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to read the text file in Python , 
for an instance if you have a file named record.txt containg dataset,

```
file <- open('record.txt')
```

now you have to read the file line by line :

```
lst = []
```

stores the whole file as a list of  list  and each inner list represents an instance

```
for line in file:
    lst.append([ float(x) for x in line.split()])
```

now you can extract the column1 as a list and column 2 as a list by following comprehension

```
column1 = [ x[0] for x in lst]
column2 = [ x[1] for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and `float` within `map` :

```
zip(*[map(float,line.split()) for line in open('in_file')])
```

Demo:

```
>>> s="""       2500.3410      -0.60960758
...        2505.5803       -1.3031826
...        2510.8197      -0.64067196
...        2516.0593       -1.0230898
...        2521.2991      -0.20078891"""
>>> 
>>> [i.split() for i in s.split('\n')]
[['2500.3410', '-0.60960758'], ['2505.5803', '-1.3031826'], ['2510.8197', '-0.64067196'], ['2516.0593', '-1.0230898'], ['2521.2991', '-0.20078891']]
>>> zip(*[map(float,i.split()) for i in s.split('\n')])
[(2500.341, 2505.5803, 2510.8197, 2516.0593, 2521.2991), (-0.60960758, -1.3031826, -0.64067196, -1.0230898, -0.20078891)]
```

But note as `zip` return a list of tuples you can use `map` function to convert the result to list :

```
>>> map(list,zip(*[map(float,i.split()) for i in s.split('\n')]))
[[2500.341, 2505.5803, 2510.8197, 2516.0593, 2521.2991], [-0.60960758, -1.3031826, -0.64067196, -1.0230898, -0.20078891]]
```